# Custom ContentPipeline with Browse facility

Tags: xna, content-pipeline

I'm writing a Custom ContentPipeline and I've added some Normal and Specular Map properties.  Everything compiles fine and works as expected.  What I'd like to do now is have the Normal and Specular properties be "browsable" when the user clicks in the box.  Currently, the user has to type the name of their normal or specular file and what I'd like is like the Font property.  When a user clicks in the Font property it has the box with the 3 `.`s.

How would I get this feature?  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to look into how to customize the property grid control:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx#usingpropgrid_topic5

In particular, look at the part that deals with type converters and how to customize the property grid editor for your property.